# WPF MVVM : Not able to bind child views control property from main view

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here I have the UserControl named “ChildView” and it has one ListView control named “listView”.
I am trying to bind the “SelectedItems” property of this listView as command parameter from my main window, but not happening.
The execute function parameter is always null.

Below is the code snippet.

```
ChildView 

<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.Views.ChildView"
…………..
    <ListView x:Name="listView" …………..


MainView

…………..
<views:ChildView   x:Name="childView" />
…………..
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=childView, Path=DataContext.CmdCopyLines}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=childView, Path=DataContext.listView.SelectedItems}" Label="Copy" />
…………..
```

But it is happening directly from child view

```
ChildView 

<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.Views.ChildView"
…………..
    <ListView x:Name="listView" 
…………..
<Button Command="{Binding CmdCopyLines}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItems}" Label="Copy" />
…………..
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On your ChildView usercontrol, are you setting its DataContext as your ViewModel and then creating the Command in your ViewModel, or is the ViewModel fully constructed and initialized before you set it as the DataContext ?

Comment: Hi Dean, my child ViewModel is fully constructed and initialized (command also) before I set it as the DataContext. From App I am creating MainWindow ViewModel object, and from MainWindow ViewModel’s constructor I am creating child ViewModel objects and finally I set Data DataContext for MainWindow , and its child View.

Answer (score 0):

Path=DataContext.listView.SelectedItems is not right in your case, because your datacontext is your childviewmodel

add a Property to your childviewmodel and bind it to your selectedItems, then you can do:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=childView, Path=DataContext.CmdCopyLines}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=childView, Path=DataContext.MySelectedItems}" Label="Copy" />
```

Comment: Here I can’t create a Property in my ChildViewModel for ListView – SelectedItems, as it is not a DependencyProperty.
Please check this link 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596732/binding-to-the-selecteditems-property-of-a-listbox-in-silverlight

One workaround to handle this scenario is, send the SelectedItems as CommandParameter.